# FTP code producing "secure connection required (code=530)"

Tags: .net, ftp, sftp

I'm using the Secure FTP product from [EnterpriseDT](http://www.enterprisedt.com/). The setup below worked for one of my projects, but it's failing with `Rejected--secure connection required (code=530)` on another that pointing to a different address.

```
Dim ftp = New EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.SecureFTPConnection _
    With {.LicenseOwner = "[REDACTED]", _
          .LicenseKey = "[REDACTED]", _
          .ServerAddress = "[REDACTED]", _
          .ServerPort = 21, _
          .UserName = "[REDACTED]", _
          .Password = "[REDACTED]", _
          .ConnectMode = EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPConnectMode.PASV, _
          .TransferType = EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.FTPTransferType.ASCII}

ftp.Connect()
```

I know all the addresses, user names, passwords, etc. are correct because I've used them all on a command-line SFTP app, so I'm assuming I'm missing something in the SecureFTPConnection setup. I've tried specifying all the valid values for SSLVersion, but that doesn't help. What is this cryptic error message trying to tell me about my setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, you are trying to connect to an FTPS (which is SSL/TLS over FTP, not equal SFTP) without proper SSL. But like i said, just a guess (from using FTPS via ProFTPD back in the day).

Comment: I've barely got a grasp of FTP, so I'm not sure I get the difference between SSL over FTP (FTPS) vs. SFTP. Which one is my example? How do I set up the other type?

Comment: Look at http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetpro/doc/api/EnterpriseDT.Net.Ftp.SecureFTPConnection.html and then protocol.

Comment: Bingo! Specifying the protocol was the missing piece. Thank you so much for the quick response.